# Gridview Row is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` in which what I want is, If the amount column is `0` or `""`. I want to hide the **Generate invoice** button. So for that what I tried is,

```
function GridExpInfo_ClientInsert() {
        for (i = 0; i < GridExpInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
            if (GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "" || GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "0") {
                GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[14].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error as

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'GridExpInfo.Rows[...].Cells.14.style' is null or not an object

Here is my `gridview` aspx

```
<cc1:Grid ID="GridExpInfo" runat="server" FolderStyle="../Styles/Grid/style_12" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          AllowAddingRecords="true" AllowColumnResizing="true" Width="100%" ShowFooter="true"
          ShowHeader="true" OnInsertCommand="GridExpInfo_InsertCommand" OnRebind="GridExpInfo_Rebind"
          OnRowDataBound="GridExpInfo_RowDataBound" OnUpdateCommand="GridExpInfo_UpdateCommand">
    <ClientSideEvents OnClientAdd="GridExpInfo_ClientAdd" OnClientEdit="GridExpInfo_OnClientEdit"
                      OnClientDblClick="GridExpInfo_OnClientDblClick" OnClientInsert="GridExpInfo_ClientInsert" />
    <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateId="tplRowEdit3" />
    <Columns>
        <cc1:Column ID="Column19" DataField="MKEY" ReadOnly="true" Width="0%" runat="server"
                    Visible="false">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="gtchkConfirm" HeaderTemplateId="HTConfirm" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="SR_NO" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Sr No" Width="4%"
                    ID="Column31">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtsrnoexp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="TYPE" HeaderText="Agreement Type" Width="8%" ID="Column51">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="ddlTypeExpData" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="STAGE" HeaderText="Stage" Width="8%" ID="Column44">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="ddlStageType" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="EXP_TYPE" HeaderText="Expense Type" Width="8%"
                    ID="Column25">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="ddlexptypExp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="EXP_ID" Width="0%" Visible="false" ID="Column43">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="PARTY_NAME" HeaderText="Party Name" Width="8%"
                    ID="Column29">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtpartynameexp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="AMOUNT" HeaderText="Amount" Width="6%" ID="Column21">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtamountexp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="REMARKS" HeaderText="Remarks" Width="10%" ID="Column24">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtremexp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="CHQ_FAVR_NAME" HeaderText="Chq in Favor Name"
                    Width="8%" ID="Column28">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtchqfavExp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="VOUCHER_NO" HeaderText="Voucher No" Width="6%"
                    ID="Column26">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtvouchexp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="CHEQUE_NO" HeaderText="Chq No" Width="5%" ID="Column27">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtChqnoExp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column Wrap="true" DataField="CHEQUE_DT" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" HeaderText="Chq Date"
                    Width="6%" ID="Column30">
            <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtchqDtExp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Column32" DataField="ATTACHMENT" HeaderText="Attachment" runat="server"
                    Width="8%" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Column20" HeaderText="Generate Invoice" runat="server" Width="8%"
                    Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="tplButtonInvoice" />
        </cc1:Column>
    </Columns>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplRowEdit3">
            <Template>
                <table class="rowEditTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <fieldset style="width: 750px; height: 310px;">
                                <legend>Expense Information</legend>
                                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="display: none;">
                                            SR NO :
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtsrnoexp" style="display: none;" class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Type :
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeExpData" runat="server" Width="250px" DataSourceID="ds_exp_type"
                                                              DataTextField="TYPE_DESC" DataValueField="TYPE_DESC">
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                                <%--<asp:ListItem Value="Agreement Type">Agreement Type</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="Expense Type">Expense Type</asp:ListItem>--%>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Stage :
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStageType" runat="server" name="ddlStageTypename" DataSourceID="sd_Type_Stage"
                                                              DataTextField="STAGE" DataValueField="STAGE" Width="250px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="display: none;">
                                        <td>
                                            Ref No :
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%--<input type="text" id="txtExpRefNo" name="txtrefNovalue" runat="server" style="width: 150px;
                                                       height: 18px; font-size: 11px;" class="ob_gEC" />--%>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpRefNo" Height="18px" name="txtrefNovalue" runat="server" CssClass="ob_gEC"
                                                         Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Ref Date :
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%-- <input type="text" id="txtExpRefDt" name="txtrefdatevalue" runat="server" style="width: 150px;
                                                        height: 18px; font-size: 11px;" class="ob_gEC" />--%>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpRefDt" Height="18px" name="txtExpRefDt" runat="server" CssClass="ob_gEC"
                                                         Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Expense Type:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlexptypExp" runat="server" DataSourceID="sd_Type_EXP" DataTextField="DESCRIPTION"
                                                              DataValueField="DESCRIPTION" Width="250px">
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="--Select--">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Amount:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtamountexp" style="width: 150px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px;"
                                                   class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Party Name:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtpartynameexp" style="width: 250px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px;"
                                                   class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Expense Details:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtremexp" CssClass="ob_gEC" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="50"
                                                         TextMode="MultiLine" Style="font-size: 11px;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Chq in favor name:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtchqfavExp" style="width: 250px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px;"
                                                   class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Voucher No:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtvouchexp" style="width: 150px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px;"
                                                   class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Chq No:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtChqnoExp" style="width: 150px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px;"
                                                   class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Chq date:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" id="txtchqDtExp" style="width: 150px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px;"
                                                   class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Attachment:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="file" id="FlAttacExp" style="width: 300px; height: 18px; font-size: 11px;"
                                                   class="ob_gEC" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="GridExpInfo.save()" class="button" />
                            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="GridExpInfo.cancel()" class="button" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <%-- <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplNumbering3">
            <Template>
                <b>
                    <%# (Container.RecordIndex + 1) %></b>
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>--%>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplButtonInvoice">
            <Template>
                <input id="Button1" type="button" runat="server" value="Invoice" style="width: 80px;" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
</cc1:Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript and C# code do not mix. Doesn't the line `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].style.display = "none";` give an error like `TableCell does not contain a definition for 'style'...` in Visual Studio?

You should use it like this:

```
GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[14].Visible = false;
```

However this will remove the cell from the grid and the columns in that row will move to the left. So to the user Cell 14 contains the content from Cell 15, 15 from 16 etc. You can fix this by applying a colspan to Cell 13, but that also means the contents of Cell 13 could overflow.

Even better would be to hide the button based on a certain value in the row.

```
<asp:Button Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("value").ToString()) || Eval("value").ToString() != "0" %>' runat="server" Text="Generate invoice" ID="Button1" />
```

UPDATE

It looks OP is using the Grid from [Obout](http://www.obout.com). That probably means that "normal" grid function work differently.

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="GridExpInfo.cancel()" class="button" style="display:<%# (Container.Value != "0" ? "block" : "none") %>" />
```

Comment: your 1st answer is not working for me. Also for second answer, what should I add here `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("value").ToString()`. My condition is, I want to hide if value is `0` or `" "`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: getting error as `DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Hashtable' does not contain a property with the name 'value'.`

Comment: `value` is the column name from the datasouce. You need to change that to get it to work for you.

Comment: but how i will get that ? Even If I write the column name it still gives me error as `DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Hashtable' does not contain a property with the name 'AMOUNT'.` Here is my code. `<asp:Button Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("AMOUNT").ToString()) || Eval("AMOUNT").ToString() != "0" %>' runat="server" Text="Generate invoice" ID="Button1" />`

Comment: That error means that there is no column with the name `AMOUNT`. It could be that `obout gridview` works different than normal gridviews. I'm installing it now.

Comment: If I have the correct grid (http://www.obout.com), then it all works differently. You have to use `Container.Value` instead of `Eval("value")`

Comment: let me check with that. but any idea with javascript as how to hide button ?

Comment: Quick testing on my side. If it works with javascript it works with others as well.

Comment: No it is giving me the error with this also, I need with JS if possible.

Comment: Are you using that grid from obout?

Comment: This time you don't need to change `Container.Value` just keep it as it is. There are a lot of examples shipped with the installer package. Experiment on those also.

Comment: I tried like this `document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_ob_GridExpInfoBodyContainer_ctl33_0_ctl00_0_Button1_0').style.display = "none";` and it worked for me. But the problem here is, the ID is changing by every row. If I handle the ID properly then my work is done

Answer (score 1):

I've given a solution for `ListView` to disable button on condition. See the sample below and quite identical to `GridView`:

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Add" Enabled='<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "1" %>' />
            <br />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Default.aspx.cs: Just paste the below code in the code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = GetAllUsers();
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        User aUser = new User();

        List<User> Users = new List<User>();

        Users.Add(new User() { ID = 1, name = "AT-2016", Status = "1" } );
        Users.Add(new User() { ID = 2, name = "AT-2014", Status = "0" } );

        return Users;
    }

    protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count(); i++)
        {
            //Get the Label by row
            Label status = (Label)ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("label3");
            Button button1 = (Button)ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("button1");

            if (status.Text == "1")
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```